# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Python.Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I ran into a problem like "value of a DataFrame is ambiguous".
I tried to use logical indexing and special symbols like '&' but it doesn't help.

I have a table

| minuts | seconds | total_sec | cost | total_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 49 | 109 | 1.5 |  |
| 0 | 57 | 57 | 0.0 |  |
| 0 | 34 | 34 | 0.0 |  |
| 2 | 0 | 120 | 2.0 |  |
| 0 | 55 | 55 | 0.0 |  |
| 6 | 47 | 407 | 4.0 |  |

I need to fill in the last column (cost) based on the following logic:

- if minuts >= 1 and seconds >= 1 then total_cost = cost + 0.5
- if minuts < 1 and seconds >= 1 then total_cost = cost + 1.5
- if minuts < 1 and seconds < 1 then total_cost = cost

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```py
def check (minuts, seconds):
    if df.loc[(df['minuts'] >= 1) & (df['seconds'] >= 1)]:
        return df['total_cost'] + 0.5

    if df.loc[(df['minuts'] < 1) & (df['seconds'] >= 1)]:
        return df['total_cost'] + 1.5

    else: return df['cost']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the required conditions rowwise to calculate the `total_cost` values:

```
def f(row):
    if row['minuts'] < 1:
        if row['seconds'] >= 1:
            return row['cost'] + 1.5
        else:
            return row['cost']
    elif row['seconds'] >= 1:
        return row['cost'] + 0.5
    return row['total_cost']

df['total_cost'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

---

```
   minuts  seconds  total_sec  cost  total_cost
0       1       49        109   1.5         2.0
1       0       57         57   0.0         1.5
2       0       34         34   0.0         1.5
3       2        0        120   2.0         NaN
4       0       55         55   0.0         1.5
5       6       47        407   4.0         4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): Which is more efficient than the costume function `import numpy as np`

```py
df['total_cost'] = np.where((df['minuts'] >= 1) & (df['seconds'] >= 1), df['cost'] + 0.5,
                   np.where((df['minuts'] < 1) & (df['seconds'] >= 1), df['cost'] + 1.5,
                   np.where(df['minuts'] < 1, df['cost'], np.nan)))
                   
print(df)
```

---

```
   minuts  seconds  total_sec  cost  total_cost
0       1       49        109   1.5         2.0
1       0       57         57   0.0         1.5
2       0       34         34   0.0         1.5
3       2        0        120   2.0         NaN
4       0       55         55   0.0         1.5
5       6       47        407   4.0         4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `df.loc[(df['minuts'] >= 1) & (df['seconds'] >= 1)]` you get the subset that fulfills the first condition, but when you add the `if` to it:

> `if df.loc[(df['minuts'] >= 1) & (df['seconds'] >= 1)]:`

Now you're trying to evaluate `if <dataframe>:` and, as the error states, the truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.

One solution without additional imports could be to get the indexes that correspond to each condition and then assign the values using `iloc`:

```
q1 = df.query('minuts >= 1 & seconds >= 1').index
df.at[q1,'total_cost'] = df.iloc[q1]['cost'] + 0.5

q2 = df.query('minuts < 1 & seconds >= 1').index
df.at[q2,'total_cost'] = df.iloc[q2]['cost'] + 1.5

q3 = df.query('minuts < 1 & seconds < 1').index
df.at[q3,'total_cost'] = df.iloc[q3]['cost']
```

Note that I used `query` but it should work with `q1 = df.loc[(df['minuts'] >= 1) & (df['seconds'] >= 1)].index`.